# Sound issue on acer c731 chromebook and I have installed kubunto 20.04

Tags: sound, acer, chromebook

I am having a sound issue that involves this random whining noise whenever I'm playing music via YouTube. It'll play fine for a good few minutes before it pauses the video and plays that noise. It affects both Firefox and Chromium, yet it won't play that sound when I'm not playing anything.

Comment: I had the same issue with the same chromebook. Here is the solution. [Long beep sound in Chromebook while playing video: sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451125/long-beep-sound-in-chromebook-while-playing-video-sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt-8086)