# Loud beep sound in Acer c731 Chromebook (RELM) while playing video: sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: error

Tags: sound, 22.04, video, chromebook

I was watching a video online, and suddenly my computer started playing a high frequency noise. The video did not pause, but the sound of the video was not audible at all. The sound stopped a while after closing the lid.

This issue occurs in YouTube videos running in Firefox web browser as well as in the FreeTube app.

I ran `journalctl -r` and saw the error message

```
sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: error: reply expected 12 got 0 bytes
```

The computer is an Acer 11 N7 C731 Chromebook (codename RELM) natively running Ubuntu MATE 22.04. It has an Intel Celeron N3060 processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround [here](https://github.com/thesofproject/sof/issues/4662#issuecomment-902725338) which involves using the `SST` driver instead the `SOF` driver.

The solution is to add the following line to the file `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=2
```

**Reboot**.

After this, the bug disappeared completely.