# Video freezing every 3 minutes on Ubuntu 22.04 on Acer R11 Chromebook

Tags: 22.04, video, freeze, acer

Converted Acer R11 Chromebox to Ubuntu 22.04 using mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript UEFI firmware replacement.
Everything works fine except any video player (firefox, vlc) freezes video about every 3 minutes. Clicking on pause and waiting a few minutes then clicking play allows the video to resume, only to freeze again after about 3 minutes.
The Acer R11 (C738T Cyan) uses an Intel Celeron N3150, Mesa Intel HD Graphics 400.
Any known fixes for this?

Comment: Can you check if there has been any ususual entries in `journalctl -r` right at the moment when the video froze? Also, how much RAM do you have?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any entries right at the failure, but when firefox starts I get two suspicious entries.

Comment: Both entries contain ALSA Lib: one ends with Uknown SEQ default, the other with Cannot access file /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf.  Machine has 4 GB memory

Comment: Can you edit the question and add the exact error message? I had a different issue (https://askubuntu.com/q/1451125/124466) in another chromebook, and found a solution by google searching the exact error message

Comment: I tried the solution from the link you provided. It seems to fix the issue when streaming video with firefox (which is great-thanks!), but playback of stored video with vlc  has audio drop-outs every few seconds.

Comment: Using firefox to play a stored video file seems to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer, provided in the link by Archisman Panigrahi in the comments. It fixes (so far) the video freezing issue using firefox, but causes erratic video in vlc (hence the partial answer).

edit /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf

and add the line

options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp-driver=2

reboot.