# Ubuntu 22.04LTS - Computer makes weird high pitch sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

So I installed Ubuntu on my system and when I am playing music after a while my speakers are making a **weird high pitch sound**. I tried `pulseaudio -k` and `pulseaudio --start` and the **high pitch sound** stops but I can hear it again after a while. (I am new to Linux)

This is the sound **(Warning High Volume Sound)**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FQHOHxYTnpovlLdKuVZgmfiXTa9Sg4m9/view?usp=share_link

Any suggestions?

Here is an output from `journalctl -r`, which has a lot of error messages from pulseaudio.

```
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: pulseaudio.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: Failed to start Sound Service.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: pulseaudio.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: Stopped Sound Service.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 6.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: Started Evolution address book service.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G dbus-daemon[1394]: [session uid=1000 pid=1394] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolut>
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: Started User preferences database.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G dbus-daemon[1394]: [session uid=1000 pid=1394] Successfully activated service 'ca.desrt.dconf'
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: Starting Evolution address book service...
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: Starting User preferences database...
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G dbus-daemon[1394]: [session uid=1000 pid=1394] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.>
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G dbus-daemon[1394]: [session uid=1000 pid=1394] Activating via systemd: service name='ca.desrt.d>
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: Started Evolution calendar service.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G dbus-daemon[1394]: [session uid=1000 pid=1394] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolut>
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: Failed to start Sound Service.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G rtkit-daemon[788]: Supervising 10 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G rtkit-daemon[788]: Successfully made thread 1834 of process 1818 owned by '1000' RT at priority>
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G rtkit-daemon[788]: Supervising 9 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G rtkit-daemon[788]: Supervising 9 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G rtkit-daemon[788]: Successfully made thread 1833 of process 1818 owned by '1000' RT at priority>
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G rtkit-daemon[788]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G rtkit-daemon[788]: Supervising 8 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G rtkit-daemon[788]: Successfully made thread 1831 of process 1818 owned by '1000' RT at priority>
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: Starting Portal service (GNOME implementation)...
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G rtkit-daemon[788]: Supervising 7 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G dbus-daemon[1394]: [session uid=1000 pid=1394] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freede>
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G dbus-daemon[1394]: [session uid=1000 pid=1394] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Shell.>
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G pulseaudio[1818]: Stale PID file, overwriting.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G rtkit-daemon[788]: Supervising 7 threads of 5 processes of 2 users.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G rtkit-daemon[788]: Successfully made thread 1818 of process 1818 owned by '1000' high priority >
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: Starting Portal service...
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G dbus-daemon[1394]: [session uid=1000 pid=1394] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freede>
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G kernel: audit: type=1326 audit(1681147629.339:57): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.>
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G audit[1823]: SECCOMP auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.snapd-desktop-integration.snap>
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: Starting Sound Service...
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: Stopped Sound Service.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: Starting Evolution calendar service...
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: pulseaudio.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G dbus-daemon[1394]: [session uid=1000 pid=1394] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.>
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: Started Evolution source registry.
Απρ 10 20:27:09 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G dbus-daemon[1394]: [session uid=1000 pid=1394] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.evolut>
Απρ 10 20:27:08 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: Failed to start Sound Service.
Απρ 10 20:27:08 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: pulseaudio.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
Απρ 10 20:27:08 TurboX-Wintab-II-3G systemd[1370]: pulseaudio.service: Main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
```

Comment: I once experienced a similar issue. Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/q/1451125/124466

Comment: now I don't have sound at all

Comment: Can you see if there is any sound related error message in the output of `journalctl -r`? (you can scroll down to expand the list). Maybe you can post the output in pastebin and share it here.

Comment: Here is the link for pastebin: https://pastebin.com/QYXseRVe