# Intermittent loud beep on a Asus C300M (former chromebook) running Lubuntu 23.04

Tags: sound, lubuntu, asus, chromebook

My chromebook was working perfectly well with Lubuntu 20.04 (running natively). The sound was always quite low but it was ok. I installed the update 22.04 and now, the sound is either terrible or there is an intermittent loud beep for a few seconds. After the beep, the sound can return to normal or disapear. I tried installing Lubuntu 23.04, same problem, I also tried the solution explained here : [Long beep sound in Acer c731 Chromebook while playing video: sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451125/long-beep-sound-in-acer-c731-chromebook-while-playing-video-sof-audio-acpi-inte)

With this solution, no loud beep anymore but a slower, low pitch voices version. I didn't try other things because I am not an expert and I couldn't really understand. I could reinstall Lubuntu 20.04, but at the price of not receiving any updates anymore. Can someone help me ?

Thank you

Comment: You didn't specify what kernel stack you were using at 20.04; as if it was for example the HWE kernel stack (5.15); that same kernel is available for 22.04 by using the GA (5.15) kernel stack... I'd thus expect you to be able to use 22.04 without issue (ie. HWE on 20.04 is GA on 22.04).  HWE on 22.04 is currently 5.19 (6.2 in *proposed* so coming) with 23.04 using 6.2. What were you using on 20.04?  Also FYI:  Lubuntu 20.04 is no longer supported by the Lubuntu team, but all packages from *main* (in common with 5 year products) still receive security fixes; only some may not get fixes.

Comment: When I type _uname -r_ it returns with _6.2.-24-generic_. But I don't know which one it was before the update.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Long beep sound in Acer c731 Chromebook (RELM) while playing video: sof-audio-acpi-intel-byt 808622A8:00: error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451125/long-beep-sound-in-acer-c731-chromebook-relm-while-playing-video-sof-audio-ac)

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the solution.

I reinstalled Lubuntu 20.04, had no sound this time. Installed Mainline to test other kernels, tried 5.15, 5.19, 6.0, 6.2, 6.4, no sound working correctly with any of them. Tried to install Gallium OS before realising the project is abandonned. I reinstalled Lubuntu 22.04, with 5.19 kernel, still beep sound from time to time. Found this discussion on Linux Mint forum https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=386118

I followed what was instructed, to add *options snd_sof sof_debug=1* to */etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf*, it worked, sound is good now.