# Ubuntu will not load and gives a screeching sound until forcibly turned off

Tags: boot

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and just recently had an update. Now when I turn on the computer, it loads all of the standard computer setup stuff then goes to black for about three or four seconds. Usually at this point, it would show a line of text across the top of the screen and then go into UBUNTU.
Instead, it stops at the line of text, which currently reads:

```
      /dev/sdf5: clean, 434236/30498816 files, 26469425/121964800 blocks
      [   10.488817] snd-au8830 0000:07:01.0: control 3:0:0:Playback PCM advanced proc
      essing:0 is already present
```

As it sits there frozen, the text lines suddenly start disappearing and reappearing. And with every off and on, it lets out a snap like an electrical charge.  At first, I thought it was the monitor frying, but the sound was coming through the speakers.After about 30 seconds I turned it off by holding down the Power Button. Every time I start it up, it reacts the same way.

I've tried getting it to boot off of an installation USB, so that I could enter with "TRY UBUNTU" and run a recovery program. Unfortunately,when I get to that section and press "TRY UBUNTU or INSTALL", it goes to a black screen with a blinking cursor and stays there.

The last thing I've done is press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F4</kbd> to open a console window and log in.  This has been successful, but while I'm in there, I don't know what to do.

Please, somebody help me. Thank you.

Comment: I had a similar problem, and this is the workaround https://askubuntu.com/a/1451126/124466. Does that work for you?