i have a sound problems
#sound problem#
"How can I resolve a persistent buzzing sound issue in Ubuntu 22.4.4 affecting both headphones and speakers? Sometimes, I also encounter periods of complete sound loss until I reboot, after which the sound works for a while before the buzzing returns. Is this likely a software problem, and if so, how can I troubleshoot and fix it?"

Try this solution https://askubuntu.com/a/1451126/124466

Please add more details about your hardware
